# Conditional user confirmation on delete cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Before I would just ask user to confirm if he/she really wants to delete any instance like this:

```
$this->Html->link($this->Html->image('delete.png', array(
'alt'=>'delete', 'title'=>__('Delete'))),
 array(
'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'delete', $user['User']['id']),
  array(
'escape'=>false, 'confirm'=>'Are you sure, you want to delete this user?'));
```

Right now user hasMany events, and I would like to check if he/she really does. That's no problem, so in the controller I would just try to get the first event his that user's id. But then, if there are any events, I would like to notify the users, that the deletion is not possible because there are related events.

I can go around and come up with  some custom javascript solution, but there has to be a cake way to do it, it is just I cant find any.

Any suggestions?

Here is the controller action as of right now:

```
public function delete($id = null,$user_id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Incorrect user id'));
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }
    if ($this->User->delete($id)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('User has been deleted'), 'positive_notification');
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'full_calendar', 'action'=>'view_for', $user_id ));
    }
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be deleted. Please try again.'), 'negative_notification');
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
```

Comment: Just updated the question with the controller action.

Comment: Yep that'll work via GET, which makes it wide open to CSRF attacks. Whilst waiting on answers I recommend investigating how to make it work _only_ by post and how to use postLink in your view. Your asked question will still be applicable as what you're asking is _effectively_ how to implement a beforeDelete method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have properly set up the model relationships like this:

```
   //User.php

   public $hasMany = array(
    'Event' => array(
        'className' => 'Event',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
    ),

  //Event.php
   public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
    ),
);


 public function delete($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('Incorrect user id'));
      $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }
    //check if User has Events
    $user=$this->User->findById($id); //you can debug first the $user so you can know the values inside the array. Given that it has many Events, events associated to the User is in the $user
    if(count($user["Event"])==0){ //if user has no events
       if ($this->User->delete($id)) { //delete user
          $this->Session->setFlash(__('User has been deleted'), 'positive_notification');
          $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'full_calendar', 'action'=>'view_for', $user_id ));
       }
       else{
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be deleted. Please try again.'),             'negative_notification');
         $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
       }
    }
    else{
         $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be deleted. Some events are associated to this User.'), 'negative_notification');
         $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }


}
```